# How to make complex condition with or/and in Helm chart.yaml?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

I have following dependency in `Chart.yaml`:

```
  dependencies:
  - condition: feature1.enabled
    name: ...
    version: ...
    repository: ....
```

I can't find in [documentation](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_best_practices/dependencies/) how to make complex condition like

```
feature1.enabled or feature2.enabled
```

or

```
feature1.enabled and feature2.enabled
```

how can I achieve it ?

Comment: There's another documentation section that describes `condition:` a little more (the linked question quotes it in detail), but in short `condition:` doesn't support Boolean logic, it just uses the first named value that exists.

Comment: ([Helmfile](https://github.com/helmfile/helmfile) is a somewhat complex tool that uses Helm-style templating to describe a set of Helm charts to execute, but that would let you supply that value using the Go text/template language, rather than building the logic into the chart.)